# Vuejs (vuex) error unknown local mutation type

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an error when I type in my input at the register page. The error said:

```
unknown local mutation type: setRegisterEmail, global type: authentication/setRegisterEmail
```

I've tried many way still can't fix it.

Here is my register.vue:

```
Import { mapState, mapMutations, mapActions } from 'vuex';
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState('authentication', [
      'registerEmail',
      'registerPassword',
      'registerError',
    ]),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations('authentication', [
      'setRegisterEmail',
      'setRegisterPassword',
    ]),
    ...mapActions('authentication', [
      'register',
    ]),
  },
};
```

Here is my autentication.js:

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        registerEmail: null,
        registerPassword: null,
        registerError: null,
        token: null,
    },
    mutation: {
        setToken(state, token) {
            state.token = token;
        },
        setRegisterEmail(state, email) {
            state.registerEmail = email;
        },
        setRegisterPassword(state, password) {
            state.registerPassword = password;
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo into your `authentication.js`. Replace `mutation` by `mutations`

Comment: lol well thank you i'm new in vuejs and I try to find the error 3 hr. thank youu! . I'll mark this answer

Answer (score 0):

I am using **[Vuex Advance Application Structure](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/structure.html)** and faced this problem. This issue was resolved by defining complete directory of **mutations** after **modules** folder e.g cart/setCartData

```
this.$store.commit('cart/setCartData', payload);
```

Image from [VuexSite](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/structure.html) is attached for better explaination of **Advance Application Structure**
[image]